# What's the shortcut key for code block?

Tags: formatting, slack

How to format a selected piece of text as a code block in [slack](/questions/tagged/slack)?

Answer (score 1):

When *writing a post* it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on Windows.